Pod doesnt seem to have attached PVC
I have created PV, PVC and added that PVC to the pod.
Problem/Question:
When adding PVC (in my understanding) it is like attaching external/additional storage.
Yet, when I connect to the pod, i dont see any additional file system. Why?
kubectl exec -it pod1 -- bash
root@pod1:/# df -Th
Filesystem                        Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                           overlay   31G  5.9G   23G  21% /
tmpfs                             tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev
shm                               tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             tmpfs    197M  2.0M  195M   2% /etc/hostname
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4      31G  5.9G   23G  21% /etc/hosts
tmpfs                             tmpfs    1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                             tmpfs    983M     0  983M   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                             tmpfs    983M     0  983M   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                             tmpfs    983M     0  983M   0% /sys/firmware

Steps to reproduce:
$ kubectl apply -f pv1.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: pvc1-volume
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/storage"

kubectl get pv -o wide
NAME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                  STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
pv1     1Gi        RWO            Retain           Available   default/pvc1-volume    manual                  4s    Filesystem

$ kubectl apply -f  pvc1.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc1-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Mi

$ kubectl apply -f pvc1.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/pvc1-volume created

$ kubectl get pvc -o wide
NAME           STATUS   VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
pvc1-volume    Bound    pv1      1Gi        RWO            manual         8s    Filesystem

kubectl apply -f pod1.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod1
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc1-volume
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx:1.16
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage

kubectl get po
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod1          1/1     Running   0          28s


When creating a PersistentVolume (PV) using the hostPath type, you're essentially pointing to a directory on the host (the worker node where your pod is scheduled) as the storage location. In your case you specified /opt/storage on the host.
When you attach this PV to your pod through a PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) and mount it to a specific path inside your container (in this case, /usr/share/nginx/html), the directory on the host (/opt/storage) gets mounted inside the container at that path.
But now from the kernel's perspective, this mount is not creating a new file system instead it is all part of the same FS, meaning it simply making a directory from the host's file system available inside the container. As a result, when you run the df -Th command inside the container, you won't see a new file system listed for /usr/share/nginx/html. Instead this directory is treated as part of the existing file system already mounted in the container (likely under the overlay type, as indicated in your df output).
